Is the transpose of an infinite Hadamard matrix also Hadamard?
Let $\omega$ be the set of non-negative integers. If $f,g:\omega\to\{-1,1\}$ are maps, then we say $f,g$ are almost orthogonal if there is a positive integer $C_0\in \omega$ such that for all $n\in\omega$ we have $$\Big|\sum_{k=0}^n \big(f(k)\cdot g(k)\big)\Big|< C_0.$$
An infinite Hadamard matrix is a map $M:\omega^2 \to \{-1,1\}$ such that whenever $i\neq j \in\omega$ then the "row vectors" $M[i,\cdot]$ and $M[j,\cdot]$ are almost orthogonal.  (Given $a\in\omega$, the map $M[a,\cdot]:\omega\to\{-1,1\}$ is defined by $n\mapsto M(a, n)$.) It takes a bit of work to show that infinite Hadamard matrices do exist.
For $M:\omega^2\to\{-1,1\}$, the transpose $M^{\text{tr}}:\omega^2 \to \omega$ is defined by $(a,b) \in\omega^2 \mapsto M(b,a)$.
Question. If $M$ is an infinite Hadamard matrix, is the transpose $M^{\text{tr}}$ also an infinite Hadamard matrix?

No. just add two rows of ones at the top.

@HenrikRüping But then $\left\lvert \sum_{k=0}^n \bigl( M[0,k] \cdot M[1,k] \bigr) \right\rvert = n+1$, which is not bounded by any positive integer $C_0$, so the first two rows aren't almost orthogonal, right?

Ah yes. I got confused with rows and columns. The stated definition here is that rows are almost orthogonal. So lets add two columns of ones add the left instead.
Then the bound $C_0$ increases by two, but the two columns are not almost orthogonal, so transposing doesn't work.

@HenrikRüping What if we relax the definition to "all but finitely many rows are almost orthogonal"?

Then we could repeat each column once. Then the bound doubles,but after transposing all pairs $(2k,2k+1)$ would violate this. What if we relax the condition further so that for a given $k$ there can only be finitely many violatings with that $k$ ?

Define $f_i(n) = (-1)^{b_i(n)}$ where $b_i(n)$ is the $i$th binary digit of $n$ (Speyer's example with $\lambda = e_i$). Then $(f_1, f_2, \dots)$ defines an "infinite Hadamard matrix" because the partial sums of $f_i(n) f_j(n) = (-1)^{b_i(n) + b_j(n)}$ (for $i \ne j$) are zero over any interval of length $2^{\max(i,j)}$. On the other hand the transpose matrix is very far from being Hadamard-like. We have $f_i(m) f_i(n) = (-1)^{b_i(m) + b_i(n)} = 1$ whenever $2^i > m, n$, so $\sum_i f_i(m) f_i(n) = +\infty$ for all $m, n$.
